# Moving to Bottom of iframe after reloading it in 5 milliseconds interval

Tags: javascript, scroll

```
   window.setInterval("reloadIFrame();",500);
    function reloadIFrame() {            
        document.getElementById("myIframe").src="/chatbox/";
        //scrollTop = document.getElementById("myIframe").contentWindow.document.body.scrollTop;
        document.getElementById('myIframe').contentWindow.scrollTo(1000000,1000000);
        
        }
```

The fucntion ScrollTo is not working and it does not scroll to bottom
I tried searching other questions too but none of them work.Please give me a simple javascript solution without any Jquery or React.

Answer (score 0):

If the content of the iFrame is not from the same origin as the page the iframe is in, then no dice. Look in the console for access errors.

If it is from the same origin, then add the scroll to the iframe load event

Something like this

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',() => {
  const iFrame = document.getElementById("myIframe");
  iFrame.addEventListener('load',function() {
    this.contentDocument.scrollTo(1000000, 1000000);
  })
  const reloadIFrame = () => iFrame.src = "/chatbox/";
  window.setInterval(reloadIFrame, 500);
});
```

You many need to add a cache buster to the /chatbox/ url

A better solution would be if you know the ID of the last chat message, then you just need

```
iFrame.src = '/chatbox/#lastMessageId'
```

Comment: 'load---> when does this string end?

Comment: Sorry, took the end quote with me when I changed from 'DOMContentLoaded'

Comment: Iframe is still not scrolling to bottom and stays in top,can u still help me solve this?

Comment: Any console errors? I would need to see it in action. Any possibility to show a test site?